# fetch api throws uncaught in promise error

Tags: javascript

I have a wrapper function for the fetch api to fetch different endpoints to my api but somehow it keeps complaining that there is unhandled rejection `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined`

```
const apiRequest = (url) => {
    return fetch()
    .then(async resp =>{
        const json = await resp.json()
        if(json.status == "success") return json
        return Promise.reject('err')
    })
    .catch(err => {
         return Promise.reject(err)
     })   
}
```

calling the function like:

```
apiRequest('/test')
.then(data => console.log(data))
 .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** When this answer was posted, the question didn't have the `return`. The OP added it afterward, claiming it was in their original code. But they also accepted the answer, so something below must have helped... :-)

---

`apiRequest` needs to *return* the promise chain. Right now, it doesn't, so calling it returns `undefined.`

```
const apiRequest = (url) => {
    return fetch(url) // *** Note: Added `url` here
//  ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
    .then(async resp =>{
        const json = await resp.json()
        if(json.status == "success") return json
        return Promise.reject('err')
    })
    .catch(err => {
         return Promise.reject(err)
    })
}
```

**But**, three things:

1. There's no point whatsoever to that `catch` handler; and
2. You need to check for response success **before** calling `json`; and
3. There's no reason for that `then` handler to be an `async` function.

Instead:

```
const apiRequest = (url) => {
    return fetch(url) // *** Note: Added `url` here
    .then(resp => {
        if (!resp.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP status " + resp.status);
        }
        return resp.json();
    })   
};
```

*(I've also added some missing semicolons there, but if you prefer to rely on ASI, just leave them off.)*

If the `fetch` promise is rejected, that rejection will be carried through to the promise from `apiRequest` for the caller to handle. If the `fetch` promise is fulfilled but `resp.ok` is `false` (because there was an HTTP level error like a 404 or 500), the promise from `apiRequest` will be rejected with the error thrown in the `then` handler. If those things work but the `json` call fails, the promise from `apiRequest` will be rejected with the error from `json`. Otherwise, the promise  from `apiRequest` will be fulfilled with the parsed data.

It can also be a concise form arrow function if you prefer:

```
const apiRequest = (url) => fetch(url).then(resp => { // *** Note: Added `url` to `fetch` call
    if (!resp.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + resp.status);
    }
    return resp.json();
});
```

---

Your original code used an `async` function in `then`. If you can ues `async` functions in your environment, you may prefer to make `apiRequest` an `async` function:

```
const apiRequest = async (url) => {
    const resp = await fetch(url); // *** Note: Added `url` here
    if (!resp.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + resp.status);
    }
    return resp.json();
};
```

Comment: I forgot to include the return but have it in my code and tried your suggested way but still getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined`

Comment: @hmaxx - Calling `apiRequest(/*...*/)` / `then` / `catch` as shown in your question with the above definitely will not cause that error.

Comment: I had syntax error when calling the apiRequest function `then(res =>console.log(res)`. That was the root cause and I missed that but this answer helped me figure it out as I had to look somewhere else for the error. Txs